# How to check for missing drivers in Ubuntu 14

Tags: drivers

Can anyone can help me to know if need to install a driver in my notebook, and where to check to see what drivers are available to be installed?.

Comment: The Additional Drivers utility is a GUI application to check for drivers in Ubuntu and there is also a terminal program to check for drivers by running the command `ubuntu-drivers devices`.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the drivers are installed by default (eg. open driver for intel/amd/nvidia chip) For closed driver search " additional driver" from dash. It will list closed driver for amd(fglrx)/nvidia or wifi driver.